# Using Exsheets with exam class

Tags: exam, exsheets

I am trying to make multiple versions of an exam. The most convenient way I have found to code this is with the exsheets package. (I haven't found a way to do it with the exsheets successor xsim.) However I receive an error message. How can I fix the error or is there a better way to do this? Mailmerge doesn't quite do what I want, in particular it messes up the point values by adding all of the points for all the versions.

Thank you for any input. Here is the most minimal version of the code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetVariations{4}

\begin{document}

\variant{4}

What is $\vary{2}{4}{6}{8} \cdot \vary{1}{3}{5}{7}$?


\end{document}
```

produces errors the first of which is " @cntfmts@err@counter@defined
{question}
l.386 ...ounterPattern* [exsheets] {question} {qu}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., '\hobx'), type 'I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined."

Comment: I would combine C++ programs with LaTeX to create truly random variations (see http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm for examples).  I can show you how, if interested.

Comment: Load the exsheets package with the noauto option and manually define the question counter using the \newcounter command.

Comment: @JohnSmith do you mind writing what that would look like? something like
\usepackage[noauto]{exsheets}

\newcounter{questions}?

Comment: @JohnKormylo thank you for the offer, maybe when I have more time I will ask you more